# What is the problem for Saudi Arabia if Turkey maintains a base in Qatar?

Tags: turkey, saudi-arabia, qatar

> Saudi Arabia-led bloc [asks Qatar](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/06/arab-states-issue-list-demands-qatar-crisis-170623022133024.html) to shut Al Jazeera, close a Turkish army base and scale down Iran ties within 10 days.

What is the problem for Saudi Arabia if Turkey maintains a base in Qatar?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, it's because Turkey is the [most powerful regional ally of Qatar](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-gulf-qatar-turkey-idUSKBN19G06H) and the country has also been [sending food supplies and exports to Qatar](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-gulf-qatar-turkey-minister-idUSKBN19E0OL) after the ties were cut. Turkey has also [provided military support](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-gulf-qatar-turkey-minister-idUSKBN19E0OL) to Qatar in addition to commercial links.

Secondly, the military base is Turkey's first in the region and was [set up to "confront 'common enemies'"](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-qatar-turkey-military-idUSKBN0TZ17V20151216) and this makes direct attacks on Qatar more difficult as Turkey is [much more likely to come to Doha's help](http://www.washingtoninstitute.org/policy-analysis/view/turkeys-new-base-in-qatar).

> "If you are a small state like Qatar you have an interest in hosting several allies on your territory because it provides you with an indirect security guarantee from your ally. Moreover, it increases the costs for the aggressor of any potential attack."

The military base also shows that Turkey’s having a greater influence in the region and Qatar’s independence from its powerful neighbors.

Thirdly, Turkish forces and Qatari forces are also [preparing for a joint security exercise](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jun/19/turkish-troops-take-part-in-joint-military-exercises-in-qatar-blockade-saudi). So, without the base, it's more difficult or impossible to conduct one. Turkey has also [sent more military troops to the base](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/tayyip-erdogan-turkish-president-qatar-ultimatum-saudi-arabia-bahrain-uae-kuwait-donald-trump-muslim-a7806871.html) to strengthen it since the ties were cut.

> The controversy comes as Turkish and Qatari forces prepare to conduct a joint security exercise, according to Al Jazeera, and is the latest flare-up in a tense standoff between Qatar and a bloc of Arab nations.

Comment: Okay. What is saudi's problem with that?

Comment: @anonymous "makes direct attacks on Qatar more difficult as Turkey is much more likely to come to Doha's help."

Comment: is this kind of thing (turkey-related stuff, asking to get rid of Al J. and blocking transportation access so the Qataris can eventually starve?) allowed under "International Law"? Or are the anti-Qataris behaving like Israel (who doesn't care about such things) or the US who only cares about I.L. when it (agrees with/is convenient for) them?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem for Saudi Arabia if Turkey maintains a base in Qatar?

The answer is very simple.

If there is a Turkish base in Qatar, Saudi Arabia can't achieve anything by imposing a sanction on Qatar.

If a sanction on Qatar doesn't work, Saudi Arabia is back with its original problem: **Al Jazeera**.